# Problem with admin member deletion system with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, foreach, datatable

What I want to do is to delete that member with the id of the current member when I click the delete member button in my admin member information panel. I did everything, but when I want to delete a member, it always takes the id of the member at the top of the table. It doesn't delete what I want next. I think it might be related to the foreach loop, but I still haven't figured it out. I would be glad if you help.

member-information-update.php

```
                 <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="users">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">#</th>
                            <th scope="col">Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Surname</th>
                            <th scope="col">E-Mail</th>
                            <th scope="col">Process</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <?php
                        $users_query     =   $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
                        $users_query->execute();
                        $query_number      =   $users_query->rowCount();
                        $all_users             =   $users_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                        foreach ($all_users as $user){
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row" class="user_id"><?php echo $user["id"]?></th>
                                <td><?php echo $user["user_name"]?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $user["user_surname"]?></td>
                                <td id="user_email"><?php echo $user["user_email"]?></td>
                                <td width="100px">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">
                                        <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="user_delete_button">
                                        <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

member-information-update.js

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("button[name=user_delete_button]").on('click', function (){
        var a_id            =   $.trim($('.user_id').html());
        var a_email         =   $.trim($('#user_email').html());

        swal({
            title: 'CAUTION! ARE YOU SURE?',
            text:  'Are you sure you want to delete the user? This action can never be undone.!',
            icon: "warning",
            buttons: true,
            buttons: ["No, don't delete", "Yes, delete it!"],
            dangerMode: true,
        })
            .then((willDelete) => {
                if (willDelete) {
                    $.ajax({
                       url: 'http://localhost/project/admin/result/member-delete-result.php',
                       type: 'POST',
                       data: {
                           'id': a_id,
                           'email': a_email
                       },
                       success: function (value) {
                           if ($.trim(value) == "successful") {
                               swal("Poof! User sent to deep space!", {
                                   icon: "warning",
                               });
                           }
                       }
                    });
                }
            });

    });
});
```

member-delete-result.php

```
<?php
require_once('../settings/db.php');
require_once('../../functions/functions.php');

    if ($_POST) {
        $coming_id               =   Security($_POST["id"]);
        $coming_email           =   Security($_POST["email"]);

        if ($coming_id) {
            if ($coming_email) {
                /*
                $control_query           =   $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? AND user_email = ?");
                $control_query->execute([$coming_id, $coming_email]);
                $number_query            =   $control_query->rowCount();
                $control_record          =   $control_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                if ($kontrol_sayisi>0) {
                    $delete_query       =   $db->prepare("DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ? AND users_email = ?");
                    $delete_query->execute([$coming_id, $coming_email]);
                    $delete_number     =   $delete_query->rowCount();

                    if ($delete_number>0) {
                        echo "successful";
                    } else {
                        echo "error1";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "error2";
                }
                */
            }
        }
    } else {
       echo 'error3';
    }

?>
```

As I said, the result returns successfully. There is no problem until here, but it operates according to the id at the top of the table. It does not process the id in the part I selected.

Comment: An `id` must be unique. You have `<td id="user_email">` in a loop so you have multiple `user_email` elements. Your `$('#user_email').html()` then just selects the first and ignores the rest.

Comment: @user3783243 so how do i do

Comment: Make `name` and `id` unique. Use a `class` to listen for event. Then select that/`this`'s a values. Could take the `id` of `this` then use that in same scope you have.

Comment: @user3783243 Can you show me how to do it?